# Eclipse IDE settings via tcl script

Tags: eclipse, version-control, tcl

I have just started to work with Eclipse based IDE (namely it is Vitis IDE from Xilinx) and I have been looking for whether it is possible to control the Eclipse IDE project settings via the tcl script. Due to linkage with the version control software I need to set the "Link folder" for my project via tcl script. Can anybody tell me wheteher it is possible to do that? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Probably not while Eclipse is running and has the project open. It tends to be very keen on caching things.

Comment: @Donal Fellows, thank you for your reaction. Do you have any idea where I can read more about that?

Comment: No idea. It's just based on my own observations over the years, and I've not really written them down very much. Occasionally mentioned to colleagues at work in passing, I guess? Doesn't really help you…